# Paging in PHP using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, paging

Hi I want to create pages on the samepage means I want to show Images from my database to PHP page and I want to show 20 images per page so when user click on 2,3,4,5 to go to next page here is my code I'm trying but it's giving me some errors.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","user");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM save_data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $start_from, 20";
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) {
    $post_id = $row['ID'];
    $title = $row['Title'];
    $image = $row['Name'];


?>


    <center>

    <a href="pictures.php?title=<?php echo $title; ?>">
    <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3></a>

    <a href="pictures.php?title=<?php echo $title; ?>">
    <img src='uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>' width='140' height='140'></a>

    </center>
<?php
};
?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM save_data";
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20);

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
            echo "<a href='pages.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
};
?>
```

**Errors which I am getting**

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\all-images.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\all-images.php on line 17

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\all-images.php on line 41

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_login\all-images.php on line 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code error I found :

you are mixing mysql and mysqli, 
be persistent

```
$rs_result = mysqli_query ($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result)){
    echo $row["table field name"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions. Those don't mix well. To get you script running properly it's easiest to replace `mysqli_connect` with `mysql_connect` as all other function are `mysql`.

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","123");
mysql_select_db("user");
```

As Mike Brant suggested in the comments, you shouldn't use `mysql` anymore but rather [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). My answer should still fix your problem though.

Comment: -1 for suggesting he use `mysql` rather than `mysqli`. Other than that the answer is correct in regards to the root problem. If you change this to reflect suggestion to update everything to `mysqli` this -1 will turn into a +1.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this.